# How to pass a variable in the url

Tags: laravel-5

This is how my line of code looks like

```
'<td class="text-center"><a href="patients/{{ $patient->id }}/edit">Edit</a></td>'
```

this table is under single quotations, I am having trouble with it.How do i get that link working? please help me

Comment: You are most definitely passing a variable in the URL already. Inspect the _value_ of that variable to check if it is what you require it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate the parmeter like this:

```
'<td class="text-center"><a href="patients/' . $patient->id . '/edit">Edit</a></td>'
```

It is not looked as a valid URL, but the string represented here contains valid URL.

Comment: Thanks, you just solved this problem,it is working fine now.